# Jenkins on EFS restore takes many hours

Tags: jenkins, amazon-efs

We have jenkins running on EFS and we also have a backup that saves jenkins_home directory to a .zip file in S3 but in case of Disaster Recovery we need to recover EFS from S3 where after uploading the file on EFS mount, it takes 5-6 hours to unzip the .zip file (about 10GB-12GB). This is unacceptable in our case and looking for alternative to unzip this file faster, not sure if we have any mount flags that are required for better performance of EFS.

Also, if we can exclude any files from jenkins home directory to reduce the actual size of the backup?

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).